# convert system._comobject to .net string

Tags: .net, com, com-interop

I'm having some trouble trying to get the values of a class's property. The implementation structure is as follows:

1. A COM object written in C# has a COM visible wrapper class that makes use of two classes with ComVisible(false) attribute.
2. COM object is called from classic ASP page to perform some work.

The non-COM visible classes have some properties of .NET types (mostly string types). The problem is that when accessing these properties in various methods in the classes the properties return System._ComObject as their value rather than their actual content. I have tried using ToString(), explicitly casting them to their .NET types, and also using InvokeMember() after getting the type of the property. But nothing seems to give the actual content value of the properties expect when InvokeMember is used which gives the actual content for some properties. All I'm getting is System._ComObject.

So my question is how do I get the actual value of these properties instead of just getting System._ComObject?

UPDATE 1:

An code sample of what I'm doing:

```
[ComVisible(false)]
public class Node
{
   public int Id
   {
       get;
       set;
   }
   public string Name
   {
       get;
       set;
   }
   public string DataType
   {
      get;
      set;
   }
  }

[ComVisible(false)]
public class Builder
{
   public Node Root;
   ASPTypeLibrary.Response response;
   public void SetUpProperties(object resp, string name, string dataType){
        response =   (ASPTypeLibrary.Response)resp;
       Root = new Node();
       Root.Name = name;
       Root.DataType = dataType;
       response.Write(Root.Name.ToString());   // This works fine
       response.Write(Root.DataType.ToString()); // This works fine
       PrintNode();
   }    

   public void PrintNode()
   {
     response.Write(Root.Name.ToString()); // This works fine. Prints actual content.
     response.Write(Root.DataType.ToString()); // This prints System._ComObject
   }
}

[ComVisible(true)]
public class Wrapper
{
  /* Required constructors are definded */

  public void Start(object resp)
  {
    Builder bld = new Builder();
    bld.SetUpProperties(resp, "Node 1", "Type 1");
  }
}
```

The Builder class is instantiated and the SetProperties() is called from Wrapper class which is created in a classic ASP page using Server.CreateObject(). The System._ComObject is printed in PrintNode(). I'm not sure what other method other than ToString() I should use to get the content of the properties.

Thanks,

Comment: Please add some code to illustrate what you are describing (it isn't easy to understand from your description either what you are doing, or where you are seeing the System._ComObject instances). String valued properties of .NET classes always return String instances. Something else must be going on in your code.

Comment: There's no scenario where a string literal "Type 1" morphs into a System.__ComObject.  Your snippet doesn't make sense.  The trouble-maker ought to be *resp*.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this : `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR()` ?